# Find img tag and replace with another tag

Tags: jquery, image, replace, src

How can I find the `img` tag and replace it with the `span` tag using jQuery?

```
<style>
    .box{
      display:inline-block;
      width:100px;
      height:20px;
      line-height:20px;
      font-size:11px;
    }
</style>

<p id="recommend">
    <img src="search.gif" alt="find"> <!-- find this img tag without id and class-->
</p>

<!-- next -->

<p id="recommend">
    <span class="box">search</span><!-- replace this -->
</p>
```

Comment: `id="recommend"`  should be unique....

Comment: I have improved the formatting of the code block, removed thanks note as it is not required, moved the description of the question to be above the code block and reworded the title and content. I have also removed the library name from title because it is not required due to presence of tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's `replace()` or `replaceWith()` methods to achieve what you are trying.

Here are the links to their usage:

https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-replacement/

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ Here is the fiddle which gives solutions to the same. And yes you cannot use sane id recommend for both paragraph tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.box{display:inline-block;width:100px;height:20px;line-height:20px;font-size:11px;}
</style>

<p id="recommend">
    <img src="search.gif" class="find"> <!-- find this img tag without id and class-->
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<span class="box">search</span>').replaceAll('img.find');
    // OR...
    $('img.find').replaceWith('<span class="box">search</span>');
});
</script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 0):

As others said, ID should be unique. Instead, you can use class for multiple element shared the same class name. Here i give an example to achieve that :

**Html**

```
<p class="recommend">
   <img src="search.gif" alt="find" />
   <!-- find this img tag without id and class-->
</p>
<!-- next -->
<p class="recommend">
<span class="box">search</span>
 <!-- replace this -->
</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.recommend').first().find('img').remove().end().html(function(){
    return $(this).siblings().find('span.box');
});
```

or

```
$('img').replaceWith(function(){
 return $(this).parent().next().find('span.box');
});
```

Add `.html()` if you want to replace the image with the content of span.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/ymcord7n/)** - Inspect element to see the replacing content.